# How to save a graph that is generated by GNU Radio?

Tags: python, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I have generated the spectrogram with GNU Radio and want to save the output graph but have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Save it how? To the disk? Is it pickleable? The documentation should say whether or not it is.

Comment: just save it on my desktop. There is no "save as" when the graph is generated and the gnuradio toolbar only saves the blocks diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "QT GUI Frequency Sink" block will display the frequency domain representation of a signal.  You can save a static image of the spectrum by accessing the control panel using center-click and choosing "Save".